# CListCtrl SetIconSpacing include text

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I'm using SetIconSpacing() in my CListCtrl icon view and the spacing is fine except I'm also displaying the image name under the image. Right now I'm forcing the spacing to `m_ctrlList.SetIconSpacing(CSize(THUMBNAIL_WIDTH, THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT+20));` where the 20 represents the text height. Is there a way to get the text height from the control?

I'm using the standard control, no funny biz.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GetTextExtentPoint32()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-gettextextentpoint32a) function. Here's what you have to do.

1. Use/Create any `DeviceContext`(CClientDC is best).
2. Get the font from the `CListCtrl` and assign the font to dc using [SelectObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162957(v=vs.85).aspx) function.
3. Now use [GetTextExtentPoint32()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-gettextextentpoint32a) function and get the font height.
4. Now set the old font back to dc.

That's it.